# git post-receive hook to trigger drush rsync without prompt or with predefined answer

Tags: drush, version-control, deployment

I have set up post-receive hook on my staging server, so whenever I push from dev server a master branch, it updates staging webroot and triggers drush rsync to update live site.

```
#!/bin/bash

    while read oldrev newrev ref
    do
      branch=`echo $ref | cut -d/ -f3`

      if [ "master" == "$branch" ]; then
    git --work-tree=/var/www/drupal/ checkout -f $branch
    drush rsync --delete --exclude='.htaccess' --exclude='io' --log-file=rsynclog.txt --exclude-files @stage @live 

        echo 'Changes pushed live.'
      fi

      if [ "dev" == "$branch" ]; then
        git --work-tree=/var/www/drupal/ checkout -f $branch
        echo 'Changes pushed to staging.'
      fi
    done
```

Or i hoped to do so :) I have ssh keys in place and that is not the problem, what i can see is that it hangs on destroy yes no question. Output after **git push origin from** dev machine:

> Counting objects: 15, done.
>
> Delta compression using up to 4 threads. Compressing objects: 100%
>   (8/8), done. Writing objects: 100% (8/8), 762 bytes, done. Total 8
>   (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0)
>
> remote: Already on 'master'
>
> remote: You will destroy data from mydomain.com:/var/www/drupal/ and
>   replace with data from /var/www/drupal// remote: **Do you really want
>   to continue? (y/n): Aborting. [cancel]**
>
> remote: Changes pushed live. To root@dev:/git/drupal 65abd19..7205946 
>   master -> master

So I would need somehow to tell script that answer is y, or I need a way to  avoid that question at all.

Also, I am not pro bash scripter ;) , are those commands being excecuted in line,  like in php, so one is not executed before other finishes ? (to make sure changes are propagated on staging webroot first, then rsynced all to live).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the --yes option to your Drush command.  This assuredly *will* work if you place it *before* the rsync directive.

For example:

```
drush --yes rsync @dev @live
```

Drush rsync is different than most Drush commands in that it uses strict option handling.  Commands that work with strict options pass *all extra flags* that appear after the Drush command name on to the tool that is being invoked.  Thus, `drush rsync --yes @dev @live` will fail, because the --yes will be ignored by Drush and passed on to rsync.

For more information, see:

[drush topic docs-strict-options](http://drupalcode.org/project/drush.git/blob_plain/HEAD:/docs/strict-options.html)

Comment: Thank heavens for the maintainers. :) Thanks Greg. +1

Comment: I had not chance to test this yet, but I bet it works as described here. I am lucky to receive an answer from a authentic Drupal Overlord :)